# Angular2: wait that service return response before show component

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have an Angular2 component, and i need to populate an attribute of an interface with some data returned by a webservice.
I've this code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.services.callMyService().subscribe(
       response => this.response = response,
       error => alert(error),
       () => this.initInterface()
    )
}


initInterface() {
    this.myInterface= {
       field1: '',
       field2: 'someData',
       fieldFromService: this.response.field
    };
}
```

but it seems that component is showed before service has do its job. In fact, if i try to access for example to field1, i obtain an error:

```
error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'field1' of undefined
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Move `this.initInterface();` after the line `this.response = response` in success call back.

Comment: Also try to initialize your object (`this.myInterface= {field1: '', field2: '', fieldFromService: ''};`) outside of initInterface()

Comment: you have to use *ngIf="myInterface" in your html code to check if data is arrived or not.you will not face undefined error if you use *ngIf. try it

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.services.callMyService().subscribe(
       response => {this.response = response;
                () => this.initInterface();
               },
       error => alert(error),

)
```

}